# Optimize mysql query statement

Tags: mysql, optimization, explain

how should I optimize this Query?

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT 
    cm . *,
    u1.Firstname AS u1Firstname,
    u1.Lastname AS u1Lastname,
    u2.Firstname AS u2Firstname,
    u2.Lastname AS u2Lastname,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    ChatMessage AS cm
        LEFT JOIN
    Users AS u1 ON cm.UserId = u1.UserId
        LEFT JOIN
    Users AS u2 ON cm.FriendId = u2.UserId
WHERE
    (cm.UserId IN (292 , 289)) AND (cm.FriendId IN (292 , 289))
ORDER BY cm.DateAdded DESC;
```

> **EXPLAIN:**
>
> 1 SIMPLE  cm  ALL fk_ChatMessage_Users1,fk_ChatMessage_Users2             238 59.24   Using where
>   1 SIMPLE  u1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mhware.cm.UserId    1   100.00
>   1 SIMPLE  u2  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mhware.cm.FriendId  1   100.00

Problem is: ChatMessage is using Foreign Keys, one on UserId and one on FriendId pointing to UserId in Users Table.

On EXPLAIN you can see it does not know how to use the Index the right way. If im adding a new Index of (UserId, FriendId) or/and (FriendId, UserId) it has 4 possibilities and does not use any of them.

This Statement is running about ever 1 second and dumps my slow-query-log-file full of junk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and add 2 indexes. One on cm.UserID and another on cm.FriendId? I dont quite understand your foreign key set up because you are using left joins, so you are saying a user can possibly not exist? Why use foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new Index on (UserId, FriendId), with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    cm . *,
    u1.Firstname AS u1Firstname,
    u1.Lastname AS u1Lastname,
    u2.Firstname AS u2Firstname,
    u2.Lastname AS u2Lastname,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (select 289 u, 289 f union all 
      select 289, 292 union all 
      select 292, 289 union all 
      select 292, 292) uf
JOIN ChatMessage AS cm ON uf.u = cm.UserId and uf.f = cm.FriendId
LEFT JOIN Users AS u1 ON cm.UserId = u1.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users AS u2 ON cm.FriendId = u2.UserId
ORDER BY cm.DateAdded DESC;
```